# Is there a term for when in Indian English stress is placed on the word "the" before a noun?

Tags: terminology, subcontinental-english, accent, stress

I often hear speakers of Indian English place stress-accent on the word "the", with a pause before finishing a sentence with a noun. There's a raised pitch and stress on the word "the", which almost makes it sound like the speaker is asking the listener to finish the sentence for them.

I'm curious if there's any research on this phenomenon, but I can't find any papers since I'm not sure if there's a term to describe it.

For example: "Today, we measured the resistance of *the*... semiconductor device"

I'd be very curious to know if this emerged from one of the native languages of India, or somehow evolved naturally while English spread throughout India.

Comment: An audio clip would help, if possible.

Comment: Stress in Indian English does not have the same role as it does in other dialects. Indian English has developed to become syllable-timed, whereas most other dialects of English (all, to my knowledge) are strongly stress-timed.

Comment: Sounds like accent. Or hesitancy in a third language. Or the mother tongue has no article (like Russian *Strong like bull*) and thus the hesitancy.

Comment: You are generalizing based on 1 Incident or on 1 Individual ; It could well be that the speaker was thinking thinking like this "Today, we measured the resistance of the ... [[what was that ? transistor ? Diode ? thyristor ? oh, well, I will use the blanket term ]] ... semiconductor device" with no other meaning !!

Comment: @Prem The OP says he often hears this, not just 1 incident or 1 individual.

Comment: I think OP is mistaken !! @Barmar , You can watch thousands of YouTube videos made by Indians where this is not occurring !! OP is generalizing based on Isolated Incidents !!

Comment: One More Possibility I can think of : This is a teacher who is looking to get responses or interaction from students who are otherwise mostly silent (a common scenario !!) and is Pausing to see whether students can fill in the words in "Today, we measured the resistance of the ... [[PAUSE & LOOK at the class, waiting for replies from students ]] ... semiconductor device" with no other meaning !!

Comment: I'm working in a school in India mentoring/training Indian teachers. This is definitely 'a thing'; all of the teachers do it, but not all of the time. I was searching the internet trying to find any name for this phenomenon and came across this post. It seems to be more prevalent when they are explaining something to a class rather than in conversation with me person to person. It doesn't happen just with 'the' either, but it's usually the penultimate word in a sentence.

Comment: @JohnH A pedagogical technique to highlight a term introduced at sentence-end?  That happens in American English as well. I had teachers in elementary school  who did the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

I am a native English speaker learning Hindi, and I don't yet know most of the words in your example, but the word order would likely be something like:

> We, today, semiconductor device's resistance, measure did do.

Notice the word order is **Subject Object Verb**, and the lack of **the**. I just think of Hindi nouns as already having a **the**. But I often have to pause while speaking a sentence to mentally re-organize the sentence parts.

My hypothesis: At least for native Hindi/Urdu native speakers, I suspect it may be a challenge to always remember to insert **the**, leading to overemphasis, and distraction from mentally lining up the noun that follows.

Comment: I speak some Bengali and see your explanation as plausible. I also note that Subcontinental English usually uses the emphatic "the" pronounced /ðiː/. I suspect that the speakers have been taught that "**the** noun" = **that particular** noun and feel that some emphasis, and a pause for effect, is required.